# Phonegap Developer: Why is My Device Not Compatible With Version?

Tags: android, cordova

I tried downloading the Phonegap Developer through Google Play, but it is showing:

*Your device is not compatible with this version*

My phone is a Techno W4 running on android 6.0. What could be the reason why my device is not compatible according to the Google Play store.

Also how do I manually download and instal the APK files on my mobile device. I am new to Phonegap and I couldn't proceed with the tutorial because of my inability to cross this stage because of this compatibility issue.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer/issues/408) github phonegap developer app issue page and check surajpindoria comment on 28 Jul 2016, on above page. It lists out Supported API level, Hardware requirements, and permissions. So if your phone is missing anything from that google play will show your device as incompatible. However [visit](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer/tree/master/resources/release) as per text in same comment **For those that are unable to install the current version from the Play Store, we do keep a copy of all released versions of the developer app here. You can download and install the version you need from there.**

Answer (score 0):

Try compile in cloud your apps from [this link](https://build.phonegap.com/), follow this process and get the apk file, then you can install in your device